# Detect Two Consecutive Single Quotes Inside Single Quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm struggling to get this regex pattern exactly right, and am open to other options outside of regex if someone has a better alternative.

The situation:
I'm basically looking to parse a T-SQL "in" clause against a text column in C#. So, I need to take a string value like this:
`"'don''t', 'do', 'anything', 'stupid'"`

And interpret that as a list of values (I'll take care of the double single quotes later):

- `"don''t"`
- `"do"`
- `"anything"`
- `"stupid"`

I have a regex that works for most cases, but I'm struggling to generalize it to the point where it will accept any character OR a doubled-up single quote inside my group: `(?:')([a-z0-9\s(?:'(?='))]+)(?:')[,\w]*`

I'm fairly experienced with regexes, but have rarely, if ever, found a need for look-arounds (so downgrade my assessment of my regex experience accordingly).

So, to put this another way, I'm wanting to take a string of comma-delimited values, each enclosed in single quotes but can contain doubled single quotes, and output each such value.

**EDIT**
Here's a non-working example with my current regex (my problem is I need to handle all characters in my grouping and stop when I encounter a single quote not followed by a second single quote):

`"'don''t', 'do?', 'anything!', '#stupid$'"`

Comment: Can't you just look for two consecutive single quotes anywhere in the input? As in: `inputString.Contains("''")`

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Can you give a non working common example u're facing

Comment: @Dusan I'm well aware of that saying, hence my noting that I am open to other approaches

Comment: `String.Split` on the comma seems like a viable alternative.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string on `', '`?

Comment: Just use a simple state machine.  Read the string character-by-character, and track whether you're currently inside single quotes or not.  As an added bonus, nobody who looks at your code needs to decipher an arcane regular expression.

Comment: @DavidArno I can't rely on there being a space between terms

Comment: I would make a simple loop through all chars and use `'` as an inside/outside alternator (if not followed by another `'`).
In loop, the switch from `outside>inside` makes new item, switch from `inside>outside` makes item complete item.
Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of maintainability, I decided against a regex and followed the advice of using a state machine. Here's the crux of my implementation:

```
string currentTerm = string.Empty;
State currentState = State.BetweenTerms;
foreach (char c in valueToParse)
{
 switch (currentState)
 {
     // if between terms, only need to do something if we encounter a single quote, signalling to start a new term
     // encloser is client-specified char to look for (e.g. ')
     case State.BetweenTerms:
         if (c == encloser)
         {
             currentState = State.InTerm;
         }
         break;
     case State.InTerm:
         if (c == encloser)
         {
             if (valueToParse.Length > index + 1 && valueToParse[index + 1] == encloser && valueToParse.Length > index + 2)
             {
                 // if next character is also encloser then add it and move on
                 currentTerm += c;
             }
             else if (currentTerm.Length > 0 && currentTerm[currentTerm.Length - 1] != encloser)
             {
                 // on an encloser and didn't just add encloser, so we are done
                 // converterFunc is a client-specified Func<string,T> to return terms in the specified type (to allow for converting to int, for example)
                 yield return converterFunc(currentTerm);
                 currentTerm = string.Empty;
                 currentState = State.BetweenTerms;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             currentTerm += c;
         }
         break;
 }

 index++;
}

if (currentTerm.Length > 0)
{
 yield return converterFunc(currentTerm);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still think about a regex-based solution, you can use the following regex:

```
'(?:''|[^'])*'
```

Or an "un-rolled" version suggested by @sln:

```
'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%5b%5e%27%5d*(%3f%3a%27%27%5b%5e%27%5d*)*%27&i=%27don%27%27t%27%2c+%27do%27%2c+%27anything%27%2c+%27stupid%27)

It is fairly simple, it captures double single quotation marks OR anything that is not a single quotation mark. No need using any look-behinds or look-aheads. It does not take care of any escaped entities, but I do not see this requirement in your question.

**Moreover**, this **regex will return matches** that are easy to access and deal with:

```
var text = "'don''t', 'do', 'anything', 'stupid'";
var re = new Regex(@"'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'"); // Updated thanks to @sln, previous (@"'(?:''|[^'])*'");
var match_values = re.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up, if you use the un-rolled loop method, the same thing turns into `'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'` with no alternation. The method can apply to any form of that type of alternation, and benchmarks 2-1/2 faster than the alternation form.

Comment: I have just tested on regexhero, and the speed increases almost 1.65 times: 274,965 iterations (with alternation version) per second vs. 455,349 iterations per second (without alternation). Nice!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Capture Collection feature, you can grab them all in a
single pass.

```
 #   @"""\s*(?:'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)'\s*(?:,\s*|(?="")))+"""

 "
 \s* 
 (?:
      '
      (                 # (1 start)
           [^']* 
           (?:
                '' [^']* 
           )*
      )                 # (1 end)
      '
      \s* 
      (?:
           , \s* 
        |  (?= " )
      )
 )+
 "
```

C# code:

```
 string strSrc = "\"'don''t', 'do', 'anything', 'stupid'\"";

 Regex rx = new Regex(@"""\s*(?:'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)'\s*(?:,\s*|(?="")))+""");
 Match srcMatch = rx.Match(strSrc);
 if (srcMatch.Success)
 {
    CaptureCollection cc = srcMatch.Groups[1].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
       Console.WriteLine("{0} = '{1}'", i, cc[i].Value);
 }
```

Output:

```
 0 = 'don''t'
 1 = 'do'
 2 = 'anything'
 3 = 'stupid'
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I do not think it works as expected, see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%0d%0a+%5cs*+%0d%0a+(%3f%3a%0d%0a++++++%27%0d%0a++++++(+++++++++++++++++%23+(1+start)%0d%0a+++++++++++%5b%5e%27%5d*+%0d%0a+++++++++++(%3f%3a%0d%0a++++++++++++++++%27%27+%5b%5e%27%5d*+%0d%0a+++++++++++)*%0d%0a++++++)+++++++++++++++++%23+(1+end)%0d%0a++++++%27%0d%0a++++++%5cs*+%0d%0a++++++(%3f%3a%0d%0a+++++++++++%2c+%5cs*+%0d%0a++++++++%7c++(%3f%3d+%22+)%0d%0a++++++)%0d%0a+)%2b%0d%0a+%22&i=%22%27don%27%27t%27%2c+%27do%3f%27%2c+%27anything!%27%2c+%27%23stupid%24%27%22+%27ff%22%22%2c%22%27%27%27&o=x)

Comment: @stribizhev - There is no comma in this adjacent text. `'#stupid$'" 'ff""` making the _field_ containing the single quote invalid. There is always boundary conditions but none was specified. In the scope of the problem, I think it works _exactly_ as my perceived expectation.

Comment: @stribizhev - and you'd have to expect the escaped delimiter to be `''` in this case. For instance, it matches `"'don''t', 'do?', 'anything!', '#stupid$''" ''ff"","'''"`

Comment: I still think you are overcomplicating. There is just no need in using Captures collection here since there is no repetitive pattern inside some leading and trailing pattern, and a simpler regex can catch everything OP needs.

Comment: @stribizhev - I don't get what you mean. Can you expand on 'overcomplicating' ? And, there is no criteria for using capture collection, it either works or it doesn't. If works, the engine stays within itself and gets it done.. always the better way.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you split on `', '`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"'\s*,\s*'");
string[] substrings = regex.Split(str);
```

And then take care of the extra single quotes by Trimming

Comment: Splitting on comma does not catch commas contained in the field data.

Comment: My answer is about splitting on commas enclosed by single quotes

Comment: Never works this way. It would split this in two:  `'here'', ''there'` when its one field. When delimiter quotes are used, You have to parse the field, not just the separator.

Comment: It works. I just tested it. It only lacked the `@` which I added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're over-thinking the problem.  A quoted string with an escaped quote looks just like two strings *without* escaped quotes, one right after the other (not even spaces between them).

```
(?:'[^']*')+
```

Of course, you'll have to remove the enclosing quotes, but you probably had to do some post-processing anyway, to unescape the escaped quotes.

Also note that I'm not trying to validate the input or work around possible errors; for example, I don't bother matching the commas between the strings.  If the input is well formed, this regex should be all you need.

Comment: This way, the first item, `'don''t'`, will be split into 2 captures, which makes it a bit more difficult to work with the obtained data. See [this demo, Table tab](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27)%2b&i=%22%27don%27%27t%27%2c+%27do%3f%27%2c+%27anything!%27%2c+%27%23stupid%24%27%22)

Comment: I'm not using the captures (I've switched to a non-capturing group to make that clearer).  That's why I said he'd have to strip the enclosing quotes; this approach doesn't lend itself to grabbing parts of the content with groups.